# Grade point average (GPA) calculator

Tags: c++

[For anyone who's unfamiliar with this grading system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grading_%28education%29).

I'd like a general review of my code, and I have a few questions:

1. Are plain types okay for the letter grades and credit hours, or could they be `public` `typedef`s?
2. Should `operator<<` need to call `calculateGPA()`, or should I create a `private` accessor and have that called?  In order to maintain encapsulation, I'll need to keep `operator<<` as a `friend`.
3. Is the `for`-loop in `calculateGPA()` ideal for this purpose, or are there one or more STL functions that can do the same thing but more cleanly?

**GPA.h**

```
#ifndef GPA_H
#define GPA_H

#include <iosfwd>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

class GPA
{
private:
    std::vector<std::pair<unsigned, unsigned> > grades;
    double calculateGPA() const;

public:
    void add(char, unsigned);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, GPA const&);
};

unsigned convertLetterGrade(char);

#endif
```

**GPA.cpp**

```
#include "GPA.h"
#include <ostream>
#include <stdexcept>

void GPA::add(char letterGrade, unsigned creditHours)
{
    unsigned numericalGrade = convertLetterGrade(letterGrade);
    grades.push_back(std::make_pair(numericalGrade, creditHours));
}

double GPA::calculateGPA() const
{
    unsigned sumGradePoints = 0;
    unsigned sumCreditHours = 0;

    for (auto iter = grades.cbegin(); iter != grades.cend(); ++iter)
    {
        sumGradePoints += iter->first * iter->second;
        sumCreditHours += iter->second;
    }

    double totalGPA = static_cast<double>(totalGradePoints) / sumCreditHours;
    return totalGPA;
}

unsigned convertLetterGrade(char letterGrade)
{
    switch (letterGrade)
    {
        case 'a':
        case 'A': return 4;
        case 'b':
        case 'B': return 3;
        case 'c':
        case 'C': return 2;
        case 'd':
        case 'D': return 1;
        case 'f':
        case 'F': return 0;
        default: throw std::logic_error("Invalid Letter Grade");
    }
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, GPA const& obj)
{
    return out << obj.calculateGPA();
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "GPA.h"
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "# Classes: ";
    std::size_t numClasses;
    std::cin >> numClasses;

    GPA gpa;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < numClasses; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "\n(" << i+1 << ") Letter Grade: ";
        char letterGrade;
        std::cin >> letterGrade;

        std::cout << "    Credit Hours: ";
        unsigned creditHours;
        std::cin >> creditHours;

        gpa.add(letterGrade, creditHours);
    }

    std::cout << "\n*** Total GPA: " << gpa;
}
```

Comment: with deciding to make letter grades and credit hours public,  I would ask, what advantage is there to making them public? But what are the disadvantages, weighed against the limitations of having them private.. I would be inclined to keep them private.. if this doesn't make sense let me know cheers

Comment: @Skippy: With `typedef`s, this is entirely different.  They generally rename a type, but doesn't have much to do with encapsulation.  They could help personalize my class a bit, plus the user obviously already knows about those two variables.  They just don't know about the `std::vector` inside the class (and even if I were to `typedef` that, it would obviously be `private`).

Comment: hey thnx for that, I wasn't sure if I understood yr point properly, I appreciate yr patience (I am here to learn you see :))

Comment: @Skippy: That's why we're here. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that I am completely unfamiliar with the american(?) grade system and GPAs -- I am reviewing the coding style and approach, not whether or not the solution is correct.

#### General notes:

- **Your** `GPA` **class is not really a class.** It's actually just a function. It could just as well be implemented as `double calculateGPA(std::vector<std::pair<char, unsigned>>)`. Beware of the golden hammer, especially when it comes to classes.
- You can use `std::tolower()` to halve the size of your `switch`.
- `v`ector comes after `u`tility in the alphabet :-)
- C++11 allows writing `>>` in nested templates.
- Your program won't compile: `totalGradePoints` is called `sumGradePoints`.
- You can probably use `float` instead of `double`.
- Make the local variables in `calculateGPA()` floating point numbers from the start, and drop the cast.
- `obj` should be called `gpa` or something like that.
- Write unit tests.

---

> Are plain types okay for the letter grades and credit hours, or could they be `public` `typedef`s?

Either is fine. Using a `typedef` makes the *intent* of a variable a bit clearer. This added distinction between types could help the developer realizing he or she is making a mistake. However, a typedef is sadly just a type *alias* and *does not create a new type!* In other words, you do not get any type-safety benefits of doing so.

To get full type safety, you would need to create a (templated) wrapper class around the types in question. Doing so would be a nice exercise when you start to learn about templates.

---

> Should `operator<<` need to call `calculateGPA()`, or should I create a `private` accessor and have that called?  In order to maintain encapsulation, I'll need to keep `operator<<` as a `friend`.

I would cache the result of `calculateGPA` and provide an accessor to it. Have `operator<<` call that accessor. This means that your class would need to invalidate the cached value whenever `grades` is modified.

---

> Is the for-loop in `calculateGPA()` ideal for this purpose, or are there one or more STL functions that can do the same thing but more cleanly?

The `for` loop is sufficiently short and sweet, and makes just a single pass (unlike most other solutions I can think of). You could always use `std::accumulate` and a lambda, but you would have to do so for both `sumCreditPoints` and `sumGradeHours`.

Am I guilty of converting you to the `const&` style? :-)

Comment: Yeah, the `typedef`s are more for aesthetics anyway.  I have barely covered templates, but it doesn't seem to quite fit my intent here (I think).  If I were to go with the first point, would there be no GPA class at all?  I suppose that means everything would be in one file, then.  Yes, I did eventually catch the includes, and I now prefer `const&` now (it reads more as "const-reference"). :-) Finally: I still cannot use a range-based for-loop for `calculateGPA()`. :/

Comment: [Is this what you mean by the "golden hammer"?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument)

Comment: With a templated wrapper class you could do `typedef unique_type_wrapper<unsigned> HourCount`, and then HourCount would be a distinct type. | You would have no GPA class, but you could still put the function in a separate file (and make helper functions in that file `static`). | Yes, and classes are a typical golden hammer. Just look at Java :-)

Comment: `unique_type_wrapper`?  Never heard of that before.  Just when I thought my code was "C++-enough," there's even more C++ I could use.  Would further discussion on this in chat be okay, even if it may involved writing code (off-topic)?

Comment: `unique_type_wrapper` is the class you write when you learn about templates to allow type-safe type aliases.

Comment: Ah.  Even then, I would need a hard lesson on templates (not asking it from you specifically).

Comment: I've also added clarification for the GPA.  Thanks for bring it to my attention!

Comment: I've now added the data member, accessor, and called `calculateGPA()` in `add()` (for updating the cache).  Is that okay to do, also considering it may impact efficiency?

Comment: I'd do lazy evaluation, i.e. I wouldn't calculate the GPA until someone asks to see it.

Comment: I was trying to do that instead, but then I would probably need to go back to calling the calculating function when outputting.  Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Something like this: http://ideone.com/HUg5Xr (The comments are intended for you and do not represent a normal commenting level.) I also added a few points to my answer.

Comment: Alright, I'll take a look at this.  If I have more questions, I'll post them on chat.